# Errors out of the blue (503 Network, X-frame errors)

Tags: error, service, network, x-frame

Out of the blue I get errors (edit: in Firebug console) thrown at me when deploying my app. I didn't change anything since last time when I deployed my app (3 days ago).

Error I get when loading the "Trust it"-page of my app is:

> Load denied by X-Frame-Options: https://portal.office.com/landing.aspx? does not permit cross-origin framing.

When I then click "Trust it" i get more errors on my app-homepage:

> "NetworkError: 503 Service Unavailable - https://cdn.sharepointonline.com/12359/_layouts/15/16.0.3222.1229/1043/initstrings.js"
>
> ReferenceError: Strings is not defined
>   https://cdn.sharepointonline.com/12359/_layouts/15/16.0.3222.1229/clienttemplates.js
>   Line 1
>
> "NetworkError: 503 Service Unavailable - https://cdn.sharepointonline.com/12359/_layouts/15/16.0.3222.1229/1043/SP.Res.js"
>   SP.Res.js
>
> "NetworkError: 503 Service Unavailable - https://cdn.sharepointonline.com/12359/_layouts/15/16.0.3222.1229/1043/strings.js"
>   strings.js

Further I am nog logged on to a network, I am just working on my laptop with an internet connection. Besides those errors the app seems to work just fine, what is even stranger I suppose.

Does anyone know where this is coming from and how to fix it? Thanks in advance!!!

Edit: 
When login on on portal.office manually I get the following warning:

> Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at [url]. This can be fixed by moving the resource to the same domain or enabling CORS. [url]

This appears to be a security issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There appears to be degraded service according to the service status page for O365.  Log into your online account and check the status.

https://portal.office.com/servicestatus/ServiceStatus.aspx

Click the yellow arrow under the SharePoint Features column for today and you can see more details.

Comment: Ah ok, so apparently it is nothing I can do myself about it. Thanks Josh!